# Доступ к массиву из другого метода

Tags: c#, winforms

Как получить доступ к переменной (массив string) в другом методе внутри одного класса, но не используя глобальных переменных? C# WinForms

Comment: сделайте массив полем или свойством класса и пользуйтесь им внутри любых методов этого класса

Answer (score 2):

Если массив объявлен внутри одного метода и ссылка на него не сохранена нигде вне этого метода, то невозможно получить к нему доступ. Нужно сохранить ссылку на этот массив в поле или свойстве текущего или какого-либо другого класса

UPD: простейший пример

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ass
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int[] _массив;

        void Фуу()
        {
            _массив = new[] {666, 13};
        }

        void Бар()
        {
            _массив[1] = 12;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Фуу();
            Бар();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Можно пример, как это делается?

Comment: @DmitryShulga вам в комментариях DreamChild уже написал. Почитайте книги по ООП в вашем языке.